# How to remove comma at the end of integer printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to get the crc32 using the polynomial of Ethernet for a hexfile and store it in another file. I am able to get the output as `0x99, 0x3A, 0xC6, 0x26,` which will be store in a `file.crc`, but there is comma at the end of the output which I don't need. What I can do here to remove when adding the output to the file?

```
Current output in file:0x99, 0x3A, 0xC6, 0x26,
Expected output :0x99, 0x3A, 0xC6, 0x26

Input file content is as below:
:02000004A0104A
:200000000D004003910000F8D9FF0E00DC0F910010A07B00004D8B0404403B0080600B64D0
:1000200000505D002F296D00F1AE1D00FB2B00007C
```

```
import zlib
def crc32(filename="input_file.hex", chunksize=65536):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f1:
        while (chunk := f1.read(chunksize)) :
            file = open('output_file.crc', "w")
            crc = zlib.crc32(chunk) & 0xFFFF_FFFF
            for i in range(4):
                byte = (crc >> (8*i)) & 0xFF
                file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')
                print(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')
crc32()
```

Comment: Before closing the file just remove 1 character back.

Comment: ... or loop till 3 and handle the last separately.

Comment: The code as shown repeatedly reopens the same output file in write mode, which effectively erases anything written to the file prior to the last iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: Also, why not use the `struct` module to unpack `crc`?

Comment: There are many ways to remove a known character from a known position in a string.  These techniques are handled in any tutorial on Python strings.  Please repeat that material and post your coding attempt.

Comment: `file.write(', '.join(f'0x{t:02X}' for t in crc.to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'little')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding the results to a string or array and then trimming the last character before printing the results. Something like this:

```py
import zlib
def crc32(filename="input.hex", chunksize=65536):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f1:
        while (chunk := f1.read(chunksize)) :
            file = open('output_file.crc', "w")
            crc = zlib.crc32(chunk) & 0xFFFF_FFFF
            result = ''
            for i in range(4):
                byte = (crc >> (8*i)) & 0xFF
                file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')
                result += f'0x{byte:02X},\n'
            print(result[:-2])
crc32()
```

**Output**

```py
0xE0,
0x24,
0x7A,
0x73
```

*Edit: See @quamrana answer for a more elegant solution.*

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off building a list of your strings and `join()` them in one go:

```py
def crc32(filename="input_file.hex", chunksize=65536):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f1:
        while (chunk := f1.read(chunksize)) :
            file = open('output_file.crc', "w")
            crc = zlib.crc32(chunk) & 0xFFFF_FFFF
            out = []
            for i in range(4):
                byte = (crc >> (8*i)) & 0xFF
                out.append(f'0x{byte:02X}')
            outstr = ', '.join(out)
            file.write(outstr)
            print(outstr)
```

Comment: quamrana:thank you so much, It worked perfectly.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `endswith()` and slicing the last character out as necessary.  If your case is more complex there are other ways to approach this, but I feel like this is simple and understandable.

```
test = 'abcd,'

if test.endswith(','):
  test=test[:-1]

print(test) # 'abcd'
```

If you are looking to remove a comma from the last of the iteration, then you want to use enumerate. Both are outlined here:

https://repl.it/@datamafia/helloandmore#main.py

Or maybe this is more complicated than string analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for-loop, `for i in range(4)`, you are explicitly writing each hex chunk with a trailing comma and space: `file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')`. The simplest option for you, given your existing code, is to replace this line:

```
file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')
```

with this:

```
if i < 3:
    file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ')
else:
    file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}')
```

or you could write this in a single line:

```
file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}, ') if i < 3 else file.write(f'0x{byte:02X}')
```